# Flutter - update CustomScrollView's scroll controller

Tags: flutter

I would like to update _scrollController's initial offset after i receive new state from bloc. Basically, this is a timeline which has to adjust to new time coming from player.

This is what I do in a stateful widget

```
   void initState() {
     _scrollController =
         ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 100); //
     super.initState();   }
```

This is CustomScrollView

```
 BlocBuilder<Timer, TimestampState>(builder: (context, state) {

      calculatedScrollOffset = state.time.pixels;
      _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: calculatedScrollOffset);

        return CustomScrollView(
          controller:  _scrollController,
          reverse: false,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          slivers: timeLinePieces,
        ),
      );
```

Unfortunatelly there is no public setter to do something like `_scrollController.offset= 200`. When I debug this code there is detailed information in debug, but once new state is coming from bloc I see 'no clients' for ScrollController.
What's the best way to achieve this? I've tried to render new Timeline widget every time I receive new `TimestampState` but this also brings no effect. Ideally I would like to use setState to bind a new value for offset and render widget again to see effects.

Comment: U need to use _scrollController.jumpTo() or .animateTo() insted of calling the constructor for ScrollController inside build.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks!

`if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
            Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () {
            _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.pixels + 0.1);
            });
          }`

Comment: Glad to have helped. But consider calling .jumpTo inside postFrameCallback. It is used to register callback methods to be executed after build. I'll show you in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    BlocBuilder<Timer, TimestampState>(builder: (context, state) {
    
          calculatedScrollOffset = state.time.pixels;
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.pixels + 0.1));
            return CustomScrollView(
              controller:  _scrollController,
              reverse: false,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              slivers: timeLinePieces,
            ),
          );
```

.postFrameCallback is used to register methods to be executed after build function is done. Relying on Duration(milliseconds: 1) is not safe.

Comment: I really like this solution with postFrameCallback. Thanks! Now I face problem with this scroll widget which is being updated from bloc and user's touch as well. User's drag event is being interrupted by new state coming from bloc.

Comment: It's easy to determine if touch is triggered by the User.
Inside of NotificationListener just  use this condition `NotificationListener(
            onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
              if (scroll is ScrollStartNotification) {
                isHumanInput = scroll.dragDetails?.kind == PointerDeviceKind.touch;`

This `isHumanInput ` flag can be used in order to temporarily disable mechanism responsible for automatic actuations of scroll positions (Bloc listener mentioned before).